# Convert Key to Value in Dataset with nested Associations

Tags: dataset, associations

Let's say I have a `Dataset` consisting of nested `Associations` (in this case, created through a `Query`) and I want to convert the first set of `Keys` into `Values`.  Is there a way to do this without having to drop the `Keys`, create a new column, and then `Join` the two together?

Consider the following example where I take the `Mean` age by sex and class of the passengers in the Titanic `ExampleData`:

```
data=ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}][GroupBy["class"], 
 GroupBy["sex"] /* KeySort, Mean, #age &]
```

[image: example dataset]

Here is what I am looking for:

[image]

And I can get it with this code:

```
final = Join[AssociationThread["class" -> #] & /@ Keys[data], 
  Values[data], 2]
```

However, the solution seems like it may take more steps than required.  Is there a simpler / more elegant code that I am neglecting?

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate. The way to get what you want with the `ungroup` function from that Q/A answer, is `data[ungroup[{"class"}]]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, It might just be me, but that example seems a lot more complicated than even the code I have used above.

Comment: Well, the general solution given by `ungroup` might look more complex than your code, but it addresses a general problem, of which yours is a special case. So I would still consider this a duplicate of that. The fact that here `Dataset` is used and there isn't, matters very little I think.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, Thanks for your input. I have spent some time looking through both examples. I certainly see the functional similarities between the questions having missed the earlier question b/c my prior searches focused on `Dataset`, `Key` and `Value`.  Ultimately, I was looking for a simpler approach and in this case, `ungroup` isn't that.  I do agree that your approach is more universal. Have you considered submitting to the function repository so it would in fact be a simple solution for a variety of situations?

Comment: Well, I can retract the close vote if you prefer - let me know. Re: WFR - I might at some point, yes.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I think our conversation, and the input on the other question, probably indicates that the answer to my question is "No, there isn't a simpler way."  That being said, it has give me a lot to think about on how to approach the problem when it is nested even deeper.  Thanks again for the insights.

Comment: Sure, was glad to help. Simplicity is a subjective matter. From some perspective, a more general solution might actually be simpler conceptually (not saying here it is necessarily the case).